# Agricola - Acreage minor improvement

Tags: agricola

The `Acreage` minor improvement in the `K (complex)` deck states that:

> When you
>   Sow, you can plant 2 grain fields on
>   this card.
>
> (This card does not count
>   as a field when scoring.)

Does this mean that when I sow, this card can be treated as if I have 2 extra plowed regular fields and hence, I can put 6 grains on it (2 from my personal supply that I planted, 4 from the general supply)?

Also, what happens during the harvest period? Do I get to remove 2 grains from this card and put it in my personal supply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can plant two grains, and get four more from the general supply. At each harvest, you'll get two grains back, exactly as if the card was two fields.

Note that you don't have to sow two grain - you can choose to just sow one, if you like (as if it was a single field, i.e. get two more from the general supply).